# UISlider sliding event when its continuous set to No

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uislider

How to detect the event when I slide the UISlider(not release, keep slide), I know `setContinues` can do so.

But my slider can't be set to continues, because I need the slider change once a time(that is touch-slide-slide-...-slide-stop only change its value for one time). Is there any way can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out It's my problem. I thought `continous` property set to `YES` will allow the `UISlider` to slide in float(While my value must be int, not float type).

`self.progressSlider.continuous = YES;` just call the value changed as long as the slider's value changed. It won't change the value to double.

`self.progressSlider.continuous = No;` When you're sliding the slider, value changed event won't be called until you release it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);
}
```